# ГРАМОТА.РУ, вопрос 265593-й

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в ответе на вопрос 265593 на сайте nev.gramota.ru говорится, что не требуется запятая в выражении *Как вы думаете к какой?*? Заодно скажите остальные случаи, когда *как вы думаете* не выделяется запятыми. И заодно скажите, правильно ли оформлены (в плане пунктуации и орфографии) заголовок и мой вопрос, или нет

Comment: Раз вас интересуют ошибки, то нельзя сказать случай и не надо запятую перед "или".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Вот как выглядит вопрос [№ 265593](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&start=6990):

> Уважаема справка! Как известно, если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова, то запятая перед ним не ставится. (Неизвестно когда.)
> Нужна ли в данном случае запятая?
> К одной из повестей Пушкина дан эпиграф. Как вы думаете_ к какой? (Здесь оборот "Как вы думаете" должен ли обособляться?)
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Запятая и в этом случае не нужна: *Как вы думаете к какой?*

• Вот как выглядят рекомендации Розенталя:

> **4.** Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится:
> <...>
> 3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): *Я бы тоже желал знать **почему*** (Л. Т.)... *Он ушёл и не сказал **куда**; Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил **когда**; Мать определяла температуру ребёнка губами: приложит их ко лбу и сразу определит **сколько**; Кто-то подал больному чашку воды, он даже не взглянул **кто**; Я не скажу **какое**, я говорю — большое несчастье.*
> <...>
> В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: *Что же надо делать? Научите, **что*** — усиленное логическое выделение местоимения; *Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понять — **что?*** (А. Т.) — постановка тире подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией.

• Вот как выглядят примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*― Значит, людям не хватает навыков публичного общения? **Как вы думаете, почему?*** (Ольга Филина, Борис Гладарев. Сварливая немота);
*Вот вы заполнили визовую анкету, верно? Больше ста вопросов. **Как вы думаете, для чего?*** (Мария Галина. Добро пожаловать в нашу прекрасную страну!);
*― Я давно обратил внимание, что русским плохо дается английский язык. **Как вы думаете, почему?*** (Вацлав Михальский. Храм Согласия);
*За право распоряжаться частью общих денег профсоюз гарантирует работодателям… **Как вы думаете, что?*** (Людмила Пирогова. Столкновение мнений);
*― Но многие ваши коллеги охотно идут в политику. **Как вы думаете ― почему?*** (Юлия Кантор. Вячеслав Тихонов: «Я ушел совсем в другую жизнь»);
*Вчера Степан Дальний заходил. **Как вы думаете, зачем?*** (Н. И. Кирюхин. Страшные годы. Пережитое).

• Вот пример из [учебника по географии](https://www.euroki.org/gdz/ru/geografiya/8_klass/geografiya-rossii-priroda-i-naselenie-8-klass-alekseev-nizovtsev-551/17):
*Массированный, нерегулируемый забор воды из артезианского слоя может привести к неблагоприятным последствиям. **Как вы думаете, к каким?***

• **Собственно ответ**
Мое решение выглядит так: знак нужен (по крайней мере — запятая) для выделения местоимения и передачи вопросительной интонации.
*Как вы думаете* = скажите, решите, определите.
А "Грамота", как мне кажется, просто руководствовалась первой частью правила, и теоретически ошибки в ее решении нет.

[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

• Заголовок я бы оформила так:
Вопрос № 265593 («Грамота»)

> Почему в ответе на вопрос 265593 на сайте nev.gramota.ru говорится, что не требуется запятая в выражении *Как вы думаете к какой?*?

Два вопросительных знака? Не... Не пойдет. Лучше так:
Почему в ответе на вопрос  № 265593 на сайте "Грамоты" говорится, что не требуется запятая в выражении "Как вы думаете к какой?"

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147170/discussion-on-answer-by------265593-); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагается правка вопроса.

**Название вопроса**: Почему перед  одиночным местоимением «к какой?» в СПП не нужна запятая?

**Содержание вопроса.**

Задано сложноподчиненное предложение: ***Как вы думаете(,) к какой?***

Об отсутствии запятой говорится на сайте Грамота.ру (вопрос 265293). Когда еще в таких случаях не ставится запятая?

Спасибо.

**Примечание.** На такой вопрос можно **сразу** получить ответ **по сути**, который отвечающий потом дополнит любыми сведениями по своему усмотрению.

Кстати, не будет необходимости в **двух** вопросительных знаках, а также **обсуждения** этой темы.

Comment: "К какой" — это уже не одиночное местоимение, это уже словосочетание. И знак вопроса нельзя, если называем слово.

Comment: Это не сочетание, а предложно-падежная форма для слова "какой". Вы совсем запутались в этих вопросительных знаках. У меня приводится запись заданного предложения.

Comment: Это никак не одиночное местоимение. Местоимение с предлогом, оно не одиночное! Нельзя два слова называть местоимением!

Comment: Докажите. А если докажете, то это в данной  теме не принципиально и не нужно. Так зачем нам ненужная информация, отвлекающая от сути?

Comment: Титулка — это лицо, она прежде всего должна быть грамотной. Разве надо доказывать, что местоимение — это одно слово? Это же аксиома. Да и доказывать надо тому, чей вопрос.

Comment: Просто уберите "одиночным местоимением".

Comment: А как вам титулка  заданного вопроса (в качестве "лица")? Если уберу, то тема перестанет быть ясной (по Розенталю).

Comment: Согласен. Но человек думает о себе, он о других не думает. Мало кто знает, что эти сайты для того, чтобы другие пользовались информацией. То есть создатели против вопросов, которые никого больше не интересуют.

Comment: Если уберёте, то станет грамотно (без логической ошибки). И знак вопроса нельзя, он к местоимению отношения не имеет, то есть он не входит в слово (местоимение).

Comment: А РЕДАКТОРЫ на что? Кстати, этот автор как раз думает, как лучше оформить, и даже спрашивает об этом. Вы ему помогли? Нет! Ваша критика мало что проясняет, а я вот предлагаю ОБРАЗЕЦ оформления и редактирования. Всем, как бы))

Comment: Но ваш образец с логической ошибкой. Кому такое надо? Ему нужна проверка грамотности его текста, а не другой вариант. То есть, к сожалению, ваш ответ бесполезен. Или напишите, зачем нужна правка. Да, помог, указал в комментарии две ошибки.

Comment: Извините, времени нет... И голосов  за ответ тоже нет ;(   Значит, такое никому не надо, здесь вы правы.